# Windows can't start service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am developing an app to install & run as a Windows service. It's still buggy and stopped unexpectedly (leaving nothing in the Windows Event log either) and when I tried to start it up again I got the error

> Windows could not start the {name of service} service on Local Computer.
>   Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly.

I restarted the computer (Server 2008 R2; a virtual machine, in case that makes a difference), no help. Uninstalled and reinstalled my service, and still get that error!

*Something* on the machine needs cleared out / refreshed so that it will attempt to start the service again. I don't want to rebuild the whole virtual machine but I'm out of ideas.

**UPDATE**

I forgot to mention that this Windows service -- exact same code & install -- is *running* on 3 other machines *without* the above error. Putting in that debugger in OnStart() still sounds like the way to go though.

Comment: Usually this is due to an unhandled exception.

Comment: that means there is some error in your code. Check the Event Log to see what info it is giving you. Also try to add a Logging mechanism so taht you can know what is wrong

Comment: Does your service access a network drive?

Comment: Nothing shows up in the Event Log unfortunately, and if the service is starting at all it must be failing before it gets a chance to write to its log file at all. And yes it does access some DFS paths.

Comment: @EastofNowhere, If you provide the code, mainly on the Startup, we can review it and possibly see the suspect code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have access to the code, you can add a method [`Debugger.Break`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.break.aspx) at the first line of the [`OnStart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onstart.aspx) method.

Once you "break" into the application investigate where the exception is thrown.

Comment: I have put Debugger.Break() at the firstline of OnStart() but it's not being hit :(

Comment: @Hari can you double check if your application compiled with Debug configuration (and not Release)?

Comment: @oleksii Yes I have compiled the application in debug mode. I figured out the problem. I hosted the service using 'set up and deployment' in visual studio which did not host the service properly( I had trouble starting the service too). Later when I installed the service using installutil.exe every thing was smooth and debug point was hit. Anyways thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

You can attach the debugger to a running service. Details at [Debug Windows Service Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a50syb3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx?ppud=4).

It's fortunate that you can replicate the problem easily. You can install the .NET Studio with code to debug your problem.

Another technique is to make the Service into a regular app. You know that the suspect code is during Startup. So simply create the app with code in the Startup function, and start debugging from there.

Good luck,

Tommy Kwee